# SwiftUI App crashes after second continuous open

Tags: swift, swiftui, crash

I have a working SwiftUI app with a start animation that appears to sometimes cause it to crash - this happens only when the user quits the app completely right before the animation reaches its endpoint and then immediately reopens the app - it skips the launch screen, goes straight to the main one, and then crashes. I have put my code below - thank you for your help.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import PDFKit

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase
    @State var inside = false
    @AppStorage("ShowLoadingScreen") var showLoadingScreen = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "ShowingLoadingScreen") as? Bool ?? true
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Rectangle()
                     .ignoresSafeArea()
                     .foregroundColor(Color("LightBlue"))
                     .navigationTitle("Home")
                     .navigationBarHidden(true)
                VStack {
                    if inside || !showLoadingScreen{
                    Spacer()
                      
                        Text("Bugle") .foregroundColor(Color("DarkBlue"))
                        .font(Font.custom("Copperplate", size: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.1))  .padding(.top, UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.015)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        .padding()
                        Spacer()
                        .navigationBarHidden(true)
                   
                           
                    NavigationLink {
                        MonthlyBugleView()
                            .navigationTitle("This Month's Bugle")
                    } label: {
                        ZStack {
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 100)
                                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.9, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.15)
                            .opacity(0.8)
                            Text("This Month's Bugle").font(Font.custom("Copperplate", size: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.05))  .padding(.top, UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.015)
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .padding()
                        }
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    NavigationLink {
                        PDFSwiftUIView(StringToBeLoaded: "SampleLink")
                    } label: {
                        ZStack {
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 100)
                                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.9, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.15)
                            .opacity(0.8)
                            .foregroundColor(Color("DarkBlue"))
                            Text("Previous Bugles").font(Font.custom("Copperplate", size: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.05))  .padding(.top, UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.015)
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .padding()
                        }
                    }

         
                    Spacer()
                    
             NavigationLink {
                 MoreWinaduStuffView()
                     .navigationBarHidden(true)
             } label: {
                 ZStack {
                     RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 100)
                         .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.9, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.15)
                     .opacity(0.8)
                     Text("More Stuff").font(Font.custom("Copperplate", size: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.05))  .padding(.top, UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.015)
                         .foregroundColor(.white)
                 }
               
             }
                    Spacer()
                    

                    } else if showLoadingScreen{
                        StartAnimationView()
                           .transition(.opacity)
                    }
                  
                }
             
                
                
                .onAppear( perform: {
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+3.5){
                        withAnimation {
                            inside.toggle()
                            showLoadingScreen = false
                        }
                       
                 
                    
                }
                }
            )
                
            }
        } .onChange(of: scenePhase) { newPhase in
            if newPhase == .inactive {
               showLoadingScreen = true
            } else if newPhase == .active {
                if inside == true{
                    showLoadingScreen = false
                }
            } else if newPhase == .background {
                showLoadingScreen = true
            }
        }
        
        
    }
   
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

and this is my `StartAnimationView`:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct StartAnimationView: View {
    let color: UIColor = UIColor(red: 29/255.0, green: 161/255.0, blue: 242/255.0, alpha: 1)
    @State var animate: Bool = false
    @State var offset: CGFloat = 0
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            //Content
            
            ZStack{
              
                Color("LightBlue")
                   
                Image("sample start")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .padding()
                    .offset(x: 0, y: offset)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .frame(width: 150, height: 150, alignment: .center)
                    .scaleEffect(animate ? UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.2 : UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.0075)
                    .animation(.easeIn(duration: 3.5), value: animate)
                    .animation(.easeIn(duration: 0.1), value: offset)
                   
                    
                
            } .ignoresSafeArea()
        }.onAppear{
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+0.3){
                offset = 8
                animate.toggle()
             
                
            }
        }
    }
}


struct StartAnimationView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        StartAnimationView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you init @AppStorage from UserDefault as it is what app storage is for. The init is for the first time you run the app.

Comment: Your actions in onChange of newPhase may confuse SwiftUI as you ask SwiftUI to show animation when going to inactive or background.

Comment: Thank you! I changed the onChange, preventing the animation from continuing when the app closes. Please post this as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your actions in onChange of newPhase may confuse SwiftUI as you ask SwiftUI to show animation when going to inactive or background.